# Levenberg's original article “A method for the solution of certain problems in least squares”

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

Does there exist any digital copy of the original article (or a transcript) K. Levenberg, *A method for the solution of certain problems in least-squares*, Quart. Appl. Math. 2 (1944): 164-168?

It is (obviously!) cited in numerous works, but the paper itself appears to have completely vanished. There seems to be not even any publisher, library, etc. proposing to buy a hard copy or anything alike. Apart from the citations all over the places, the paper has ceased to exist?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](https://doi.org/10.1090/qam/10666) might be better. The paper is now open access and the pdf is searchable.

Answer (score 2):

This question has been asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/178535/21564). I have replicated the accepted answer by Christian Clason below.

> As far as I can see, there's no official digitized copy (yet), but I have a hard time agreeing with your statement that no library has a hard copy. For example, looking at the German [Zeitschriftendatenbank](http://dispatch.opac.dnb.de/), you can see that many universities have a copy of that issue, and if you (or someone you know) are at a German university, will probably send you a scanned copy upon request (look for "Fernleihe: Ja").
>
> EDIT: Since there's no full bibliographical detail for the articles in such an old journal, you have to search for the *journal* (i.e., "Quarterly of Applied Mathematics") and not the article. This will get you a search result (it's the second in the list; the first is to the online version), and clicking "Link zum Gateway" at the bottom of the tab "Details" will lead to the "Gateway Bayern", where you will find a link to "SFX", where you can click on "Dokumentlieferung: Fernleihe im Bibliotheksverbund Bayern". Since I no longer have an account at TUM, I cannot follow from there, but I expect you will be presented with a form where you can enter the precise reference (title, volume, issue, pages etc.) you want to have sent.
>
> Of course, this is not nearly as convenient as getting a current online publication, but that's why librarians are still needed. Moral of the story: If you can't find it online (in reasonable time), take the full reference and ask your librarian. They're trained to help you with precisely such a problem!